# Change WHMCS Navigation color

Tags: css, whmcs

I'm trying to change the color of my WHMCS account dropdown but it is not working. Here's my style:

```
.navbar-main {
background-color: #000000;
}

.navbar-main li.account {
background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Only the main navbar changes, please see screenshot: https://prnt.sc/t4flya

You can access the site here: https://my.terahost.co.za/

Regards.

Comment: In the link that you posted the style of ".navbar-main li.account" is not like in your post..

Comment: @shai_sharakanski It's because I'm logged in.

Answer (score 0):

On my end the entire navbar is black, as supposed to be.

Change the hover effect or remove it totally since it looks like that you posted the issue while hovering.

```
.navbar-main .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
   background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, I am logged in though.

Comment: That shouldnt change the style of your page... when I visit your site the entire navbar is black, onl yon hover of the dropdown it turns blue.

Comment: Please look at this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/t4g4ha when I change that background color it works but when I copy that entire css value it does not work.

Comment: sorry Im not getting your point. When I use my suggested code it works just fine.

Comment: Hi there, I figured out the problem. My browser; the new edge is not refreshing the page correctly even after clearing cache, everything is working on chrome though xD

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Vexagon cool, glad it worked. Consider upvoting or accepting my answer then, would be much appreciated.